# value receive null with post method in the java spring controller

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, spring-boot

I try to make an API call with the `post` method via postman to my spring boot application.
Here is the input:

```
{
  "username": "name",
  "password": "1234",
  "age": 12,
  "salary": 5000,
  "role": 1
}
```

Here is the code in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
        try {
            System.out.println(user.getUsername()); // => name
            System.out.println(user.getPassword()); // => 1234
            System.out.println(user.getSalary()); // => 5000
            System.out.println(user.getRoleDto()); // => null
            System.out.println(user.getAge()); // => 24
            userService.save(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("insert done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

All properties print their value except the `user.getRoleDto()`, it always `null`. But, when I try to use this (below code) in the controller, it print the whole object exactly like the input object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity){
    try {
        String json = httpEntity.getBody();
        System.out.println(json);
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("insert done");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Here is my User.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column
private String username;
@Column
@JsonIgnore
private String password;
@Column
private long salary;
@Column
private int age;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
// getters and setters
```

Here is my Role.java

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
private String roleName;
// getters and setters
```

Here is my UserDto.java

```
private String username;
private String password;
private int age;
private long salary;
private RoleDto roleDto;
```

Here is my RoleDto.java

```
private Long id;
private String roleName;
```

What went wrong here? Any help would be very helpful. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Burm87, I took the option 1 from his suggestions in the answer. But, somehow the spring still see role_id as null, even the value is printed now. Here is in the userServiceImpl:

```
    @Override
    public User save(UserDto user) throws Exception {
        User newUser = new User();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, newUser, "password");
        // above line is refer to [here][1].
        newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        try {
            userDao.save(newUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
            // this throw "Column role_id cannot be null"
        }
        return newUser;
    }
```

But, if I use below code, the `setRole` method is `not applicable` since I define `user.getRole()` in the DTO as `int` but define `newUser.setRole()` in the `User` entity as `Role`. But if I change the `setRole` in `User` entity as `int`, then, how I can tell the spring about the `ManyToOne` relation between `User` and `Role`? Note: I think I just want to make the input parameter for `role` to be just an `integer` as provided above.

```
@Override
public User save(UserDto user) throws Exception {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    newUser.setAge(user.getAge());
    newUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());
    newUser.setRole(user.getRole()); // here is the problem
    try {
        userDao.save(newUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    return newUser;
}
```

Comment: If you are sending 1 for role in your request how would it be able to map it to what you want?

Comment: You should send an object `{id: 1, roleName: name}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

1) you keep the request you have and you change this field `roleDto` in your DTO to be an Integer field named `role` (renaming getter and setter accordingly);

2) you keep your DTO as it is and you change your request sending:

```
{
  "username": "name",
  "password": "1234",
  "age": 12,
  "salary": 5000,
  "roleDto": {
      "id": 1,
      "roleName": "your role name"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @burm87, I mark this as accepted answer, cause its already answer my original questions. But, would you please help me with the problem as I just stated in the updated question above? I choose to take the option one. The result printed, but spring still throws error 'role_id' column cannot be null

Comment: @Akza maybe doing so you will confuse people who are going to read this. Why don't you open a new question? I will take a look anyway!

Comment: thank you very much. I'll try to make another question and tell you here

Comment: @Akza I think the problem may be here `BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, newUser, "password");` when you are mapping from DTO to entity, clearly not all fields are properly mapped.

Comment: I just post another question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55731749/spring-hibernate-did-not-get-the-value-of-parameter, ur help might be very helpful. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

role is null, because In UserDTO you have RoleDto. So you need to rename "role" to "roleDto" as it is a complex object ,it will have its own json. Please replace it with the following Json and see it works. Please follow this [tutorial](https://www.journaldev.com/2324/jackson-json-java-parser-api-example-tutorial) for more understanding.

```
{
  "username": "name",
  "password": "1234",
  "age": 12,
  "salary": 5000,
  "roleDto": {
"id":1
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because in your json you have `"role": 1` and in dto - `user.getRoleDto()`. There is a mismatch between names, so it cannot be properly mapped. Try changing field name from `roleDto` in `UserDto` into `role`.