# spring hibernate did not get the value of parameter

Tags: java, spring-boot, crud

I try to make an API call with the `post` method via postman to my spring boot application.
Here is the input:

```
{
  "username": "name",
  "password": "1234",
  "age": 12,
  "salary": 5000,
  "role": 1
}
```

Here is the code in the controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<?> saveUser(@RequestBody UserDto user) {
        try {
            System.out.println(user.getUsername()); // => name
            System.out.println(user.getPassword()); // => 1234
            System.out.println(user.getSalary()); // => 5000
            System.out.println(user.getRole()); // => 1
            System.out.println(user.getAge()); // => 12
            userService.save(user);
            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("insert done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Here is my User.java

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
@Column
private String username;
@Column
@JsonIgnore
private String password;
@Column
private long salary;
@Column
private int age;
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private Role role;
// getters and setters
```

Here is my Role.java

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "role_name", nullable = false)
private String roleName;
// getters and setters
```

Here is my UserDto.java

```
private String username;
private String password;
private int age;
private long salary;
private int role;
// getters and setters
```

Here is my RoleDto.java

```
private Long id;
private String roleName;
// getters and setters
```

**Problem**: it throws error `'Column 'role_id' cannot be null'`

Here is in the userServiceImpl:
Below line (`BeanUtils`) is refer to [here](http://appsdeveloperblog.com/dto-to-entity-and-entity-to-dto-conversion/).

```
    @Override
    public User save(UserDto user) throws Exception {
        User newUser = new User();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, newUser, "password");
        newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
        try {
            userDao.save(newUser);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception(e);
            // this throw "Column role_id cannot be null"
        }
        return newUser;
    }
```

But, if I use below code, the `setRole` method is `not applicable` since I define `user.getRole()` in the DTO as `int` but define `newUser.setRole()` in the `User` entity as `Role`. But if I change the `setRole` in `User` entity as `int`, then, how I can tell the spring about the `ManyToOne` relation between `User` and `Role`?

```
@Override
public User save(UserDto user) throws Exception {
    User newUser = new User();
    newUser.setUsername(user.getUsername());
    newUser.setPassword(bcryptEncoder.encode(user.getPassword()));
    newUser.setAge(user.getAge());
    newUser.setSalary(user.getSalary());
    newUser.setRole(user.getRole()); // here is the problem
    try {
        userDao.save(newUser);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception(e);
    }
    return newUser;
}
```

Note: I think I just want to make the input parameter for `role` to be just an `integer` as provided above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are receiving 1 for the role in your request you should do something like:

```
Role role = new Role();
role.setId(user.getRole());
role.setRoleName("some name");
newUser.setRole(role);
```

In the first part of the code the problem may be here `BeanUtils.copyProperties(user, newUser, "password");`, if you try to debug or print `newUser` after that line you will see that BeanUtils was not able to populate correctly all the fields of your `newUser` object. And this is because in the destination (newUser) the field `role` is of type `Role`, while in the source (user) the type of that field is just int.

Comment: Well, when I try to print newUser.getRole(), it print null. Then, maybe, I want to ask your opinion, what is the best practice (most common used) to do this? The objective is: I just want to store the id of user role in the user table inside role_id column.

Comment: @Akza if you do not care about the role name, just remove it from everywhere, if you care about it you should get it from somewhere. Did you try my snippet above?

Comment: Well, it works. I think I just have to use this. Thanks a lot, sir!